# Handle null in JPQL query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

```java
@Query("SELECT new com.abc.cba.domain.Attachment(ia.createdBy, ia.fileName, ia.contentType, ia.someClass, ia.otherClass) from Attachment ia where ia.someClass=?1")
Attachment findAllBySomeClass(SomeClass someClass);
```

Constructor:

```java
public Attachment(User createdBy, String fileName, String contentType, SomeClass someClass, OtherClass otherClass) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.contentType = contentType;
    this.someClass = someClass;
    this.otherClass = otherClass;
}
```

If the values for `ia.createdBy`, `ia.fileName`, `ia.contentType`, `ia.someClass`, `ia.otherClass` are `null`, then the `Attachment` object gets created where all the property values are `null`.

When I call the method like below

```java
Attachment attachment = repository.findAllBySomeClass("attachment");
Long userid = attachment != null ? attachment.getCreatedBy : 0L;
```

The above statement throws a null pointer exception. When I debugged the code, I can see that the attachment object exists like
`Attachment@564435` with the hashcode and all the property values such as `fileName`, `createdBy` inside the attachment object are `null`. But why does `attachment.getCreatedBy` throw a null pointer exception in this case as it should have returned `0` when the attachment is `null`. Can you please help with this as I am confused why this code is throwing an exception?

Comment: You can use "switch case" to check "null" before executing the query.

Comment: @AnotherOne I am just confused why is this throwing a null pointer exception. Can you explain?

Comment: What is `Long userid = attachment != null && attachment.getCreatedBy : 0L;` supposed to do? I doubt it compiles. Is this intended to be a ternary operator?

Comment: @JensSchauder I am sorry it was a typo and I just fixed it in the post. Yes, it is a ternary operator.